# XPath to only select elements with specific inline elements

Tags: xpath, xsl-fo

I'm looking for an expression which only selects nodes where there is no text around a specific inline element:

```
<list>
    <item> <!-- I want this node -->
        <paragraph>
            <link>
                Installing the driver
            </link>
        </paragraph>
    </item>
    <item>
        <paragraph>
            mixed content example
            <link>
                The tablet active area
            </link>
            more content
        </paragraph>
    </item>
</list>
```

So, basically I want to select items which do not contain mixed content or paragraphs which only contain link elements and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `/list/item[not(paragraph[* and text()[normalize-space()]])]` to select `item` elements that don't contain a paragraph with mixed contents (i.e. text nodes and element nodes).

Comment: Thanks! I only had to delete "* and" to make it work how I wanted
(/list/item[not(paragraph[text()[normalize-space()]])])
Your explanation was very helpful!